# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Error: failed to pull docker images: Command /bin/sh -c docker-compose pull failed with error exit status 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-registry

When I try to deploy my nodejs application unto AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I keep coming back with this error:

`[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to pull docker images: Command /bin/sh -c docker-compose pull failed with error exit status 1.`

EB is able to pull my S3 bucket with my config.json file and download the credentials, but it still can't pull my image from dockerhub.

I've tried to run my application locally and it does work, but when I try to deploy it it comes back with this error. Has anyone come across this issue? I've been trying to find a solution for over a week now with not much progress except for .sh file needing to be executable, but even after doing that, the error stays the same.

I would appreciate any tips!

Comment: Did you look at the logs? It should have more information about your error. If you elected to send logs to Cloudwatch you can view them there, or you can view them through the EB console depending on your deployment policy.

Comment: Yes! I ended up looking at the logs and finding out that my security key needed to be converted so that it could be read properly. It took a bit of time to figure out that that was the error, but completely worked once it was done!